# Polygon border algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, shapes, border

I have an array set of (x,y) values that define a polygon. The polygon is drawn based on the point's position * a pencil size. The thing is that i want to draw the border of such shape, ignoring the inner vertexes. See this example, the BLACK vertex are the ones i'm interested in, i want to get rid of the YELLOW ones.

[image]

I'd like to get the X in another array, ordered clockwise. Been thinking about evaluating every point to see if has a neighbor and where (north, south, east, west) but seems like too much crunching to check in every vertex and i believe must be another proven and more elegant algorithm.

Any tip?

Comment: I don't understand what "inner vertexes" are, but it sounds like maybe you want to find a convex hull: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull

Comment: Could you explain a bit _The polygon is drawn based on the point's position * a pencil size._?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your "points" are just little squares, it sounds like your inner points (those which don't contribute to the border of the shape) are just those where `(x-1,y)`, `(x+1,y)`, `(x,y-1)`, and `(x,y+1)` are also all points.

You can do that test quickly by putting all of your points in a hashtable (or one of many other indexed structures).

Ordering clockwise just requires walking the border.  You have to decide what you'd like to do about holes, if there are any.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, a polygon is defined by an outline. That's an unfortunate format you have to deal with there.

If they're laid out like that (in rows with the same y coord) then you can just sort the array, first by x and then by y, then take the first point, the two points around any change in y, and the last point to form your outline.

If the real state of things is a little messier, then you might want to look into 'alpha shapes'. Some links: http://biogeometry.duke.edu/software/alphashapes/, http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~godfried/teaching/projects97/belair/alpha.html

Comment: Nice tip. I knew I needed to ask to SO for a fresh idea. I've been messing with this for more than 4 hours and was already burnt out. Your solution is simple and intuitive.

Comment: @Gabriel A. Zorrilla - Note that my first suggestion doesn't get the vertices in clockwise order. It shouldn't be too hard to get every odd/even pair of vertices around the y coordinate change though.

Comment: Your reply is valid for simple shapes, see my graphical example.

Answer (score 0):

Make sprite borders, place it same position every square and sorting oderlayout behind